# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Failing to install requirements.txt on deployment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have tried the similar problems' solutions on here but none seem to work. It seems that I get a memory error when installing tensorflow from requirements.txt. Does anyone know of a workaround? I believe that installing with --no-cache-dir would fix it but I can't figure out how to get EB to do that. Thank you.

Logs:

```
----------------------------------------
Collecting tensorflow==2.8.0
  Downloading tensorflow-2.8.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (497.6 MB)

2022/02/05 22:08:17.264961 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 2. Stderr:ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 338, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 482, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 349, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 201, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 281, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 292, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 527, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 213, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 94, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 145, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 144, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 65, in read
    self._close()
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 52, in _close
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 309, in cache_response
    cache_url, self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 72, in dumps
    return b",".join([b"cc=4", msgpack.dumps(data, use_bin_type=True)])
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/__init__.py", line 35, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 960, in pack
    self._pack(obj)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 943, in _pack
    return self._pack_map_pairs(
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 1045, in _pack_map_pairs
    self._pack(v, nest_limit - 1)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 943, in _pack
    return self._pack_map_pairs(
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 1045, in _pack_map_pairs
    self._pack(v, nest_limit - 1)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 889, in _pack
    return self._buffer.write(obj)
MemoryError
 

2022/02/05 22:08:17.264976 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2022/02/05 22:08:17.265065 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1644098897,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1644098897,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
```

Requirements.txt:

```
absl-py==1.0.0
asgiref==3.5.0
astunparse==1.6.3
awsebcli==3.20.3
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
botocore==1.23.49
cachetools==5.0.0
cement==2.8.2
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.11
colorama==0.4.3
cycler==0.11.0
Django==4.0.2
django-crispy-forms==1.14.0
django-environ==0.8.1
flatbuffers==2.0
fonttools==4.29.1
future==0.16.0
gast==0.5.3
google-auth==2.6.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.43.0
h5py==3.6.0
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.10.1
imutils==0.5.4
jmespath==0.10.0
keras==2.8.0
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.3.2
libclang==13.0.0
Markdown==3.3.6
matplotlib==3.5.1
numpy==1.22.2
oauthlib==3.2.0
opencv-python==4.5.5.62
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==21.3
pathspec==0.9.0
Pillow==9.0.1
protobuf==3.19.4
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pyparsing==3.0.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.26.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.8
semantic-version==2.8.5
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
tensorboard==2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorflow==2.8.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.24.0
termcolor==1.1.0
tf-estimator-nightly==2.8.0.dev2021122109
typing_extensions==4.0.1
tzdata==2021.5
urllib3==1.26.8
wcwidth==0.1.9
Werkzeug==2.0.2
wrapt==1.13.3
zipp==3.7.0
```

Comment: @Marcin I ended up going with Opalstack as they were cheaper but yeah, I would’ve gone with a t2.small should I have stayed with AWS. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says `MemoryError`. You must upgrade your ec2 instance to something with more memory. `tensorflow` is very memory hungry application.